# Thread-safe servlets

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

When we create servlet, why class variables(**instance and static variables**) are NOT thread-safe?

**Why methods `doPost()` and `doGet()` are thread-safe?**

I think that each new request to servlet container creates new instance of servlet class (which extends `HttpServlet`). This each instances have they own class variables that are hosted in memory, then w**hy we must make these variables thread safe?**

Comment: Normally the container will not create a new instance of the servlet for each request.

Comment: you need to know where class variables and local variables are placed in jvm.what are the  scope of these variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The servlet is instanciated only once: at loading. Then when clients make a requests, it's threaded.

This explains why you have to put monitors where it is necessary, etc.

Since doGet and doPost depend on a request, it is thread-safe : if you plan to do atomic operation in doGet and doPost, you should consider creating synchronized method/block.

Comment: thanks. i.e. if I have class with not thread-safe  class variable, I should to use this variable inside doGet(doPost) method in synchronized block or I should transfer code that use this variable into synchronized method and use this method in doGet(doPost)?

Comment: If i had to do that, i'll use a setter which would be a synchronized method.

Answer (score 0):

> When we create servlet, why class variables(instance and static variables) are NOT thread-safe?

[Servlets](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) typically run on multithreaded servers. So a servlet must handle concurrent requests and should be careful to synchronize access to shared resources. Shared resources include in-memory data such as **instance or class variables** and external objects such as files, database connections, and network connections. Since multiple threads may mutate the state of shared data, shared data is not thread safe.

> Why methods doPost() and doGet() are thread-safe?

**doPost()** and **doGet()** are thread safe if you are using local variables in those methods. If you mutate the state of  shared variables (**instance or static variables**) in these methods, **doPost()** and **doGet()** are not thread safe.

> This each instances have they own class variables that are hosted in memory, then why we must make these variables thread safe?

One instance exists for one Servlet. Requests like `doGet()` or `doPost()`  create multiple threads on same instance. As long as you use local varaibles in these methods, code is thread safe.

You can find good info in this post:

[How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-sessions-shared-variables-and-multithreadi)